# Ext JS DataIndex

Tags: extjs

I created a grid using extjs library.

First created a model:

```
Ext.define('Option', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'OptionId',
    fields: [
        { name: 'TradeDate' },
        { name: 'OptionType' }
    ]
});
```

Second I created columns array:

```
var allColumns = [
    {
        text: 'Option Id',
        width: 75,
        sortable: true,
        cls: 'grid-header-LadderStep',
        dataIndex: 'ExternalId',
        renderer: RenderColumn
    },
    {
        text: 'Trade Date',
        width: 65,
        sortable: true,
        cls: 'grid-header-LadderStep',
        dataIndex: 'TradeDate',
        renderer: RenderColumn
    }
]
```

In column list `renderer` event is define below:

```
function RenderColumn (value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {
    metaData.style = 'background-color:#BBD5EE !important';
    return value;
};
```

How can I know from the `RenderColumn` function, `dataindex` that I defined in column list?

It can be `ExternalId` or `TradeDate` in case that I described.

I found a solution:

```
grid.columns[colIdx].dataIndex
```

Where grid is a global grid variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so, this has not been documented yet by the Sencha team, but it's available. You have to do it using a method available on the header container on the grid's `Ext.grid.View`:

```
    renderer: function(val, meta, rec, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {
        var column = view.getHeaderAtIndex(colIdx);
        var dataIndex = column.dataIndex;
    }
```

The reason this works is because `Ext.grid.View` inherits from `Ext.table.View` which has a method, `getHeaderAtIndex`, that is supposed to be public, but has not been documented yet.

I found out that certain things aren't documented yet via [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?135042-How-to-get-column-of-cell-context-menu-in-ExtJS4)

Comment: wait... this won't work, due to index not matching up potentially... I will revise

Comment: How can I define field name ?

Comment: It's in the definition of your Model. If you look at your `fields` config option, you will see that each field was defined with a `name`.

Comment: Yep, I'm in the process of finding out if Ext4 exposes enough information.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify 'defaultRenderer' and then use this.dataIndex.
Like this:

```
{
    text: 'Trade Date',
    width: 65,
    sortable: true,
    cls: 'grid-header-LadderStep',
    dataIndex: 'TradeDate',
    defaultRenderer: RenderColumn
}
```

Now you can use this.dataIndex in your renderers.